# How should I test a method that calculates value using another method from another class using junit?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit

I am new in junit and I am trying to test my methods using junit testing framework. I discovered that some of my methods were passing test case while some were failed. After some time I found only the methods were passing which are not using any other method. So I need to know what should be the approach to implement a unit test for a method that is dependent on another method from another class. How can I make them test case pass successfully?

Please see my code and let me know where is the missing point?

```
// This is my method that I am trying to use for the unit test.  
@Override
    public List<Log> viewLog(long id,String type) {
        String query = "from Log ";
        QueryCondition qd = new QueryCondition();   
    qd.setIgnoreCount(true);
        qd.addAndCondition("id", "=" , "long", id);
    qd.addAndCondition("Type", "=" , "String", type);
    List<Log> result = findByCustomNamedQuery(query, qd);   
       return result;
    }
```

```
//This is my test method, I put the same result for both expResult and result to test if this returns true or not, only for checking purpose.
@Test
    public void testViewLog() {
        long id = 0L;
        String type = "my_type";
        LogDaoImpl instance = new LogDaoImpl();
        List expResult = instance.viewLog(id, type);
        List result = instance.viewLog(id, type);
        assertEquals(result, expResult);

    }
```

I am expecting true for this assertEquals but getting error.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the fact that you're calling a method from another class. If the test fails, it means that the two lists are not equal. Why could two lists not be equal? 1. they don't even have the same length 2. the objects they contain are not equal. You just need to understand why the lists are not equal. My guess is that your Log class doesn't override equals() and hashCode(). Also, please don't use raw types (List instead of List<Log>).

Comment: is it normal that expResult and result are both assigned the value of instance.viewLog(id, type)? maybe the error for this test is caused by how the test is implemented. in test scenarios you can call all the methods you want.

Comment: So are you trying to say that If my target method is dependent on some other method which is not in the same class than it is ok and should pass the test?

Comment: Java code is Java code. JUnit doesn't care, and doesn't even know what your method is doing. And BTW, it will  almost always use methods from other classes: String is a class, List is a class.

Comment: Than why my test is not passing? I have checked the passed method by adding extra function call, it failed this time. So I am sure, if I run test on my target method and target method call another method, it will fail.

Comment: I already told you that in my first comment. Here we go again: if the test fails, it means that the two lists are not equal. Why could two lists not be equal? 1. they don't even have the same length 2. the objects they contain are not equal. You just need to understand why the lists are not equal. My guess is that your Log class doesn't override equals() and hashCode().

Comment: I mentioned earlier, both expected and actual are calling the same method. So obviously they have the same value, no doubt here.

Comment: Create a class Foo, with nothing in it. Create a `foo1 = new Foo()`. Create a `foo2 =  new Foo()`. Test if they are equal. Read my comment again. If you don't know what an equals() method is, read the javadoc of Object.equals(). You should definitely have a huge doubt.

Comment: And if you don't trust me, at least trust what the computer is telling you. if it tells you that the two lists are not equal, then the two lists are not equal. Be rational, and thus ask youself why the two lists are not equal.